# issue with frames in chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am facing an issue with frames with this particular code throwing an error:

```
window.parent.frames["searchoutput"].document.open("text/html");
```

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'open' of undefined**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var frame = window.parent.frames["searchoutput"];
var frameDocument = (frame.contentWindow.document || frame.contentDocument);
frameDocument.open("text/html");
```

or more comprehensive version to check how to get document:

```
var doc;
if (iframe.document)
    iframe.doc = iframe.document;
else if (iframe.contentDocument)
    iframe.doc = iframe.contentDocument;
else if (iframe.contentWindow)
    iframe.doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: actually my code window.parent.frames["searchoutput"].document.open("text/html"); works for firefox and ie but not for chrome and your code also not working.

Comment: hi guys anyone please help me out on this issue as it is on urgent basis

Comment: Do you want to show that iframe in new window? If so try: `window.frames["searchoutput"].window.open("text/html");`